# Как вернуть цикл?

Tags: c++

Написал код, все отлично, однако когда у меня спрашивает продолжить или нет, я выбираю продолжить, он не начинает все с начала, а сразу же выдает 2 cout'a.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "1. Copy File" << endl;
    cout << "2. Move File" << endl;
    cout << "3. Rename File" << endl;
    cout << "4. Delete File" << endl;
    cout << "5. Format Disc" << endl;
    cout << "6. Search" << endl;
    cout << "7. Clear Cash" << endl;
    cout << "8. Download File" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    char v = getch();
    do { 
        if (v=='1') 
            cout << "Copy File Function" << endl; cout << endl;    
        {
            char path1[100], path2[100];
            cout << ">> Type First Adress <<" << endl;
            cin.getline (path1, 100);
            cout << endl;
            cout << ">> Type Second Adress <<" << endl;
            cin.getline (path2, 100);

            CopyFile(path1,path2, true);
            cout << endl;
            cout << " File is Copied " << endl ; cout << endl;
            cout << " Do you want to continue? (Y/N)? " << endl;
            cin >> v;
            if( v == 'y') {
                system("cls"); 
            }
        }

    } while (v != 'n');     

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Вот после нажатия "Y" он очищает экран, но сразу же выдает

```
>> Type First Adress <<
```

а за ним

```
>> Type Second Adress <<
```

Вопрос:

> Как сделать, чтобы нажатия "Y" он зачистил экран и выдал все с нуля,
>   как бы я перезапустил программу, снова он выдал меню
>   (1,2,3,,4,5,6,7,8) и просил меня выбирать 1 из этих процессов?

Надеюсь смог донести свои мысли

Comment: У Вас явно ошибка в коде - 
if (v=='1') cout << "Copy File Function" << endl; cout << endl;    
{...
по-видимому Вы хотели выполнить блок начинающийся с { по результатам проверки if(...) - однако он у вас выполняется безусловно

Answer (score 1):

Как я уже писал, преимущество cin.getline перед cin>> в том, что cin>> считывает строку до первого пробела, а getline - до конца строки. А в адресе файла вполне могут оказаться пробелы.

А проблема в том, что после чтения cin>> символа из строки в буфере ввода остается еще символ перевода строки, оказавшийся там после нажатия клавиши Enter. Чтобы его оттуда убрать надо использовать метод cin.ignore, например, так:

```
cin >> a;
cin.ignore (10, '\n');
cin.getline (b, 50);
```

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы после того как я нажал NO он опять вывел навигацию(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) чтоб при выборе я мог делать новый процесс, и при этом надо добавить новый код MoveFile для кнопки 2, код знаю, но куда и как, нет ( поможете?

Answer (score 0):

У тебя неправильно выставлен опратор do. Вот так должно заработать:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{ 
**do**{cout << "1. Copy File" << endl; cout << "2. Move File" << endl; cout << "3. Rename File" << endl; cout << "4. Delete File" << endl; cout << "5. Format Disc" << endl; cout << "6. Search" << endl; cout << "7. Clear Cash" << endl; cout << "8. Download File" << endl; cout << endl;

char v=getch(); if (v=='1') cout << "Copy File Function" << endl; cout << endl;
{ char path1[100], path2[100]; cout << ">> Type First Adress <<" << endl; cin.getline (path1, 100); cout << endl; cout << ">> Type Second Adress <<" << endl; cin.getline (path2, 100);

CopyFile(path1,path2, true); cout << endl; cout << " File is Copied " << endl ; cout << endl; cout << " Do you want to continue? (Y/N)? " << endl; cin >> v; if (v=='y') {system("cls"); }}

}
**while** (v != 'n'); system("PAUSE"); return EXIT_SUCCESS; }
```

Comment: помоги пожалуйста, он жалуется на "}" а я не могу найти куда надо его вставить (

Answer (score 0):

Вот вроде бы рабочий по вашему сценарию код! И пожелание - научитесь пользоваться переводом строки с помощью "n", а то от массы cout<<endl в глазах рябит!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

void main(int argc, char *argv[]){
char v='y';
do{
cout << "1. Copy File" << endl; 
cout << "2. Move File" << endl; 
cout << "3. Rename File" << endl; 
cout << "4. Delete File" << endl; 
cout << "5. Format Disc" << endl; 
cout << "6. Search" << endl; 
cout << "7. Clear Cash" << endl; 
cout << "8. Download File\n" << endl;

v = getch();
if (v=='1') {
cout << "Copy File Function\n" << endl; 
char path1[100], path2[100]; 
cout << ">> Type First Adress <<" << endl; 
cin>>path1; 
cout << "\n>> Type Second Adress <<\n" << endl; 
cin>>path2;

CopyFile(path1,path2, true); 
cout << endl; 
cout << " File is Copied\n" << endl ; 
cout << " Do you want to continue? (Y/N)? " << endl; 
cin >> v; if (v=='y') system("cls"); 
}
} 
while (v != 'n'); 
system("PAUSE"); 
}
```

Comment: учту в будущем! спасибо, но вот все же та же самая проблема ( закончил все, нажимаю "Y" -^ enter, нажимаю на 1, а он сразу выдает мне 
>> Type First Adress <<
>> Type Second Adress <<

не ведет себя как в первый раз, не ждет чтобы я ввел адреса, а сразу First и Second

Comment: Вот попробуйте сейчас, должно работать!

Comment: да, действительно сработала! так проблема была в cin.getline?

Comment: Возможно! :) Лично я всегда пользуюсь cin>>! Но здесь что кому удобнее!

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы после того как я нажал NO он опять вывел навигацию(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) чтоб при выборе я мог делать новый процесс, и при этом надо добавить новый код MoveFile для кнопки 2, код знаю, но куда и как, нет ( поможете?

Answer (score 0):

замените проверку

```
v = getch();
if(v == '1')....
```

на блок switch (я добавил обработку клавиши '0' - добавьте в меню '0 - выход'):

```
void main()
{
bool continue_cicle = true;
bool invalid_command = false;
while(continue_cicle)
{
 // очистить экран,
 // печатать меню
 if(invalid_command)
 {
    cout << "Введена недопустимая команда. Повторите ввод." << endl;
    invalid_command = false;
 }
v = getch();
switch(v)
{
  case '1': // копировать
      // блок кода копирования - а лучше, выделите копирование 
      // в отдельную функцию и вызовите эту функцию отсюда.
      break;
  case '2': // переместить
      // код перемещения, или вызов функции
      break;
  // ... обработка других команд
  case '0': // команда выхода
      continue_cicle = false;
      break;
  default:
      invalid_command = true;
      break;
}
if(continue_cicle && !invalid_command)
{
  // была выполнена одна из функций
  // спросим пользователя о продолжении
  // если ответит нет - присвоим continue_cicle = false;
}
}
}
```